# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, datetime, spring-mvc

There is a `Spring MVC` app where the customer has the option to place an order. You can set the date and time of the order in the order. I don't have a `frontend` at all so I'm testing methods via `swagger`. When I enter a date in the `swagger` field how should it be stored in the database by default `2020-03-11 09:25:00.000000` returns a `json` error, and in the application console, it issues a warning. I don't know what to do. Please help me solve this problem.

JSON:

```java
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-21T07:57:50.511+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.sql.Date] for value '2020-03-11 09:25:00.000000'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
  "path": "/customer/make/order"
}
```

Class Order:

```java
import java.sql.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_order", schema = "public")
public class Order {

    public Order() { 

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private Date dateOrder;

    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private boolean orderStatus;


    // Relationships
    //
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Customer customer;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "basket_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // Join without Cook in User class
    private Basket basket;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Cook cook;
}
```

CustomerService:

```java
public void makeOrder(String address, String phoneNumber,
                          Long cookId, Long basketId, Date dateInput) {

        double coast = calculateCoast(basketId);

        Customer customer = customerRepository
                .findByIdAndUserRole(User.getCurrentUser().getId(), User.ROLE_CUSTOMER);

        if (coast <= customer.getWallet()) {
            customer.setWallet(customer.getWallet() - coast);
        } else {
            throw new MainIllegalArgument("There is not enough money in the account!");
        }

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        order.setAddress(address);
        java.sql.Date date= new java.sql.Date((dateInput).getTime());
        order.setDateOrder(date);
        order.setOrderStatus(true);
        order.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByIdAndUserRole(User.getCurrentUser().getId(), User.ROLE_CUSTOMER));
        order.setCook(cookRepository.findByIdAndUserRole(cookId, "COOK"));
        order.setBasket(basketRepository.getById(basketId));
        orderRepository.save(order);
    }
```

CustomerController:

```java
@PostMapping("/make/order")
    public void makeOrder(String address, String phoneNumber,
                          Long cookId, Long basketId, Date dateInput) {

        customerService.makeOrder(address, phoneNumber, cookId, basketId, dateInput);
    }
```

My Test datas:
[image]

Im ny project I use: `Spring Boot` + `Spring MVC` + `Spring Security` + `Jpa` + `Hibernate` + `PostgreSQL`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. From your data it seems that `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is the right class to use instead.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` was for a date without time of day (I say *was* because it’s outdated, today it’s for nothing). Was that also your intended use?

Comment: `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.OffsetDateTime';`

Comment: Then you need either of two. (1) In JSON give the offset either with a colon, `+00:00`, or as `Z`, it means the same. Or (2) write a custom JSON deserializer/mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `@Temporal` annotation at your date fields

```
@Column(name = "date_order")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateOrder;
```

`Temporal.DATE` : This provides the SQL Date without the time
`Temporal.TIME` : Provides the time of the day with hours minutes and seconds
`Temporal.TIMESTAMP` : Provides the timestamp (date and time ) SQL type upto nanosecond precision

You can do the conversion at the controller level

```
   @PostMapping("/make/order")
   public void date(@RequestParam("dateInput") 
      @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date dateInput, //other request params.) {
        // Call to service.
    }
```

You can use your own format as well `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date fromDate` Or you can format the date in your service layer. For more information, read [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters)

Comment: No. It didn't help. The error is the same. I tried this with sql.Date and the same with util. Date. There's no change!

Comment: @ArturVartanyan I've updated my answer. Have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the @Temporal annotation to your date attributes

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "date_order")
private Date dateOrder;
```

Comment: No. It didn't help. The error is the same. I tried this with sql.Date and the same with util. Date. There's no change!

Comment: what is the column type of date_order in db?